# Base class with a vector<int> member

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector

I'm trying to create an abstract base class that I intend the derive classes to implement a `vector<int>` member. My problem is if I try to do this:

```
class BaseClass
{
public:
    virtual int GetCount() = 0;
    virtual vector<int> ChildData;
}

class CID1 : public BaseClass
{
public:
    int GetCount()
    {
        return 3;
    }

    //and so on.....
}
```

I get

1. 'virtual' not permitted on data declarations
2. 'virtual' is not allowed.

What I'm trying to do is:

1. make my child classes override the vector because they will contain different number of the vector elements
2. To be able to loop through an array of `BaseClass*` containing addresses of declared child classes, and the second loop for the data of the vectors.

Am I doing it the right way? Thanks in advance!

*Note: I have no prior experience in coding in C++.*

Comment: Member data cannot be virtual or overridden because they are data. Besides, `vector` is already runtime resizable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I doing it the right way?

No.

As the compiler lets you know, you can have `virtual` member functions but not `virtual` member variables.

Change the member variables to member functions and make sure you implement them properly in the derived classes.

```
class BaseClass
{
   public:
      virtual int GetCount() = 0;
      virtual vector<int>& GetChildData() = 0;
}

class CID1 : public BaseClass
{
   public:

      // virtual keyword is not necessary here
      // but helps with understanding code.
      virtual int GetCount()
      {
         return 3;
      }

      virtual vector<int>& GetChildData()
      {
         return data;
      }

   private:
      vector<int> data;

}
```

Comment: For completeness you could add private vector of ChildData as a member of derived class